# Get content of JSON or XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, get

I'm trying to get the numbers from *editcount* in this JSON:

http://es.ben10.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=users&ususers=Benfutbol10&usprop=editcount&format=json

or this XML:

http://es.ben10.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=users&ususers=Benfutbol10&usprop=editcount&format=xml

How can i do that? I tested previously but I can't get any results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var jsonString = "{\"query\":{\"users\":[{\"userid\":982510,\"name\":\"Benfutbol10\",\"editcount\":29012}]}}";

    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);

    alert(obj.query.users[0].editcount);
});
```

Here an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2KFH/1/)

Alternatively, if you want to load your json from the given url, you can do it with the help of an AJAX request.

The following code will do the same but it will load the json dynamically from the given URL

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://es.ben10.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=users&ususers=Benfutbol10&usprop=editcount&format=json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data.query.users[0].editcount);
        }
    });
});
```

Here the same example with ajax: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2KFH/2/)

Comment: Thanks for responding! The username (in my case, Benfutbol10) and the editcount (29012) is comprobated when a user enter to a page. Example: var username = encodeURIComponent(wgUserName); // http://es.ben10.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=users&ususers=" + username + "&usprop=editcount&format=json // var editcount = <editcount> // <editcount> == >50 // $('body').fadeIn();.

Comment: ok, got it. you want to have something like this? [Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/C2KFH/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Your url doesn't support jsonp so you have to do it with server side language this is a sample code for php

```
<?php
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://es.ben10.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=users&ususers=Benfutbol10&usprop=editcount&format=json'));
echo '<pre>';
print_r(current($content->query->users)->editcount);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

if you want to use json from remote server here is an example http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#example-0 but remember to read data from cross domain using javascript you have to set up jsonp in that server.

Comment: Thanks for responding!

My idea is put the number in a variable, and do a comprobation (if user == +30 editions, appear div); but only I have access to JS and CSS files.

Comment: Than do a ajax call to your server read the remote url content and return the result